# Tikz-UML Sequence diagram: Form

Tags: tikz-uml

I want to make a sequence diagram, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}

\umlobject[no ddots]{Thread1}
\begin{umlfragment}[type=States, label= {\shortstack{BufferState1 \\ == \\ BufferFree}}, inner xsep=10]
    \begin{umlcallself}[op={\shortstack{BufferState1=BufferOccupied}}, dt=5]{Thread1}
        \begin{umlfragment}[type=loop, label= \shortstack{Counter \\ != \\ Buffersize}, inner xsep=10]
            \begin{umlcallself}[op={MakeProtocol(ProtoBuffer1)}]{Thread1}
            \end{umlcallself}
        \end{umlfragment}
        \umlcreatecall[no ddots, dt=7, x=5]{Thread1}{Thread2}
        \begin{umlcallself}[op={CliendSend()}, dt=7]{Thread2}
            \begin{umlcall}[op={FreeBufferCB(BufferState1)}, type=asynchron]{Thread2}{Thread1}
            \end{umlcall}
        \end{umlcallself}
    \end{umlcallself}
\umlfpart[\shortstack{BufferState2 \\ == \\ BufferFree}]
    \begin{umlcallself}[op={\shortstack{BufferState2=BufferOccupied}}]{Thread1}
        \begin{umlfragment}[type=loop, label= \shortstack{Counter \\ != \\ Buffersize}, inner xsep=10]
            \begin{umlcallself}[op={MakeProtocol(ProtoBuffer2)}]{Thread1}
            \end{umlcallself}
        \end{umlfragment}
        \begin{umlcall}[op={create}]{Thread1}{Thread2}
            \begin{umlcallself}[op={CliendSend()}, y=5]{Thread2}
                \begin{umlcall}[op={FreeBufferCB(BufferState2)}, type=asynchron ]{Thread2}{Thread1}
                \end{umlcall}
            \end{umlcallself}
        \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlcallself}
\umlfpart[\shortstack{BufferState1 \\ == \\ BufferOccupied \\ \&\& \\ BufferState2 \\ == \\ BufferOccupied}]
    \begin{umlcallself}[op={Exit(EXIT\_FAILURE)}, padding=5]{Thread1}
    \end{umlcallself}
\end{umlfragment}

\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}    

\end{document}
```

Now i want to shift a few things, as shown with the red arrows in the picture. The red squares are the parts i want to cut, to make these boxes shorter. Is there a way to do this?

This generates a lot of errors when building. Most of them are from the \shortstack instruction. Is there are correct way to make this newline?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is missing a `\end{document}`. In addition, an indentation of the code would be helpful for readability

Comment: @dexteritas alright, sorry! I fixed the code!

Comment: You get errors even if you remove all `\shortstack`s and `\\`. Are you able to make the diagram work properly without them?